# JavaScript function scope

Tags: javascript, scope

Can someone explain to me why db is shown as undefined in the console given the following code:

```
function connect(){
   var db="Connected to";
  logConnection();
}

function logConnection(){
   console.log(db);   
}

connect();
```

This is obviously a simplified example but in reality I'm working with nodeJS and mongodb.  The `db` variable is in reality a connection to a database on which I want to perform queries.  If I can understand this in more detail, it would greatly help with my debugging.

Answer (score 2):

The variable "db" is defined in "connect", not "logConnection".  Variables in JavaScript are **lexically scoped**, which means that what matters is the static nesting inside functions, not the dynamic relationships at runtime as one function calls another.